# Dependencies when using compass with jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Currently I'm using jekyll-1.4.3 with compass-0.12.3 and sass-3.2.14, which works properly when I run

```
jekyll serve --baseurl "" --watch
```

I tried updating to sass-3.3.3, however, there were a number of dependencies that broke this setup. sass-3.3.3 is only compatible with compass-1.0.0.alpha.19. And compass-1.0.0.alpha.19 is in turn dependent on listen-1.1.6.

Attempting to run the aforementioned jekyll serve command gave the following error messsage:

```
Unable to activate compass-1.0.0.alpha.19, because listen-1.3.1 conflicts with listen (~> 1.1.0)
```

And I can't remove listen-1.3.1 because ultimately, jekyll-1.4.3 requires it. My question is, with all these convoluted dependencies, does anyone have a way to use the latest version of sass on a jekyll site right now?

Comment: Well, there are a number of improvements that come with Sass 3.3 which I would like to use, namely source maps which allow viewing of the sass code in the browser and parent selector suffixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came up with a workaround, that may not be the best idea, but for my situation, it was sufficiently viable.

I was relying on a limited number of Compass functions for my project, and I just removed the Compass gem altogether and manually called those relevant Compass files (downloaded off the github repo) instead. I also used Autoprefixr for vendor prefixing purposes.

I understand that for people who use a large range of compass functions this may not be viable. But this workaround allowed me to use the latest version of SASS, which was more important to me than Compass, to be honest.